# Vert.x how to call a file in module

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I have a module like this structure:

```
module_root/
    mod.json
    filestore/myfile
    com/my/www/my.groovy(Compiled to my.class)
```

I want to call `filestore/myfile` in `my.groovy`. I tried many methods to access the file, but I failed.

First, I try to use relative path. Both `../../../filestore/myfile` and `filestore/myfile` failed. `No such file or directory`.

```
new FileInputStream('../../../filestore/myfile').withStream {
    // ...
}
```

Then I try to use absolute path, I don't know how to get the module's absolute path. I try to get the `my.groovy` path use this code:

```
scriptFile = getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
```

But when I exec `vertx runzip mymodule.zip`, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'location' on null object
```

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `/filestore/myfile`?  ie: `getClass().getResourceAsStream('/filestore/myfile').text`

Comment: Hi @tim_yates. I followed your code, but throw an exception: ``java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'text' on null object``

Answer (score 0):

for me this works..please let me know if works for you:

```
this is js, I don't know groovy but I suppose than must be similar
var CURRENT-DIRECTORY = new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath()
```

then you can use string concatenation

```
CURRENT-DIRECTORY+"/filestore/myfile/mysuperFile.groovy" <--notice the /
```

remember than the response is a buffer, maybe you must be convert this to string

```
return response.toString()
```

good luck